# How to write a lisp function which would have in his arguments a choice among several outputs options (i mean by output several possible operations )

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

Hello i try to write a lisp function or a macro which would have in his arguments a choice among several outputs options (i mean by output several possible operations  )

Thanks

Patrick

Comment: As questions go, this is very unclear. Could you expand on what you are wanting to know?

Comment: Seems like you are describing `if` and `cond`. How would this be different?

Answer (score -1):

You can add a type specification to you function. Like that:

```
(defun foo (bar)
  (declare (type (member :blah :minor)
                 bar))
  (princ bar))
```

Then, if you call it with right value, it will work like expected:

```
CL-USER> (foo :blah)
BLAH
:BLAH
```

But calling with wrong value: `(foo :not-supported)` will cause an error:

```
The value
  :OTHER
is not of type
  (MEMBER :MINOR :BLAH)
when binding BAR
   [Condition of type TYPE-ERROR]

Restarts:
 0: [RETRY] Retry SLIME REPL evaluation request.
 1: [*ABORT] Return to SLIME's top level.
 2: [ABORT] abort thread (#<THREAD "repl-thread" RUNNING {1002478003}>)
```

Comment: This isn't right.  From the spec: 'During the execution of any reference to the declared variable within the scope of the declaration, the consequences are undefined if the value of the declared variable is not of the declared type.': so your second incantation of `foo` in fact has undefined behaviour.  Note that some implementations (notably CMUCL & its derivatives) do something more useful, but the language itself does not say you must.

Comment: Don't sure I completely understand. Do you mean that signaling error is an implementation specific?

Comment: Yes: the implementation could do anything at all.